# Delay window.print() until page has loaded within an ajax request to avoid a blank print screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do with this code is make an ajax request to something that generates barcodes and returns them to be printed. When I make the request it generates everything correctly but the print window is blank. If I cancel the print window, the underlying window has the correct barcodes to be printed. I'm suspecting that I need to delay the .print() until the child window has been fully loaded, but the solution is eluding me. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var barcode = $.ajax({
     url: "barcode.php",
     method: "POST",
     data: {
            name : name,
            text : text,
            number : numLines
            },
});
var printText;
barcode.done(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    printText = jqXHR;
    var WindowObject = window.open();
    WindowObject.document.writeln(printText);
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();

});
```

This is all wrapped in a $( document ).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a great bit of research, I found two answers: one that is probably better convention-wise, and one that is easier to implement, but (sadly) also pretty hacky.

For the first solution, it's just simplifying the second solution. Just **supply a url to `window.open`** which results in a page that will have the content and a script that calls `window.print` when everything is loaded. This should be easy as you seem to be hosting the pages here, so you can just make "barcode.php" accept GET parameters and all you need to do is add the print functionality to the page.

```
// Assumes parameters provided are safe to use in a url.
window.open('barcode.php?name=' + name + '&text=' + text + '&number=' + number');
```

Then, in the content that's sent back from "barcode.php", add a script:

```
document.onload = function() {
    window.focus();
    window.print();
    window.close();
};
```

This is far better than any other solution I can think of, especially because you *should* (I didn't test this, so I don't really know) be able to use the `load` event or `onload`.

---

I'm only providing the hacky solution for two reasons: I spent a little while on it and it may prove useful one day. I would like to stress, however, that **this second solution is pretty silly.** I would advise against using it in a production environment and

If you care to use it, here's how it goes:

- Create a window with `window.open`
- `write` (or `writeln`) whatever content you want to the new window.
- `write` a `<script>` containing some functionality to the new window:

  - Check if `document.readyState` is "complete"; if so, do your print procedure. Otherwise:
  - Use `setTimeout` to recheck `document.readyState` just like above. (Basically, repeat in some way.)
  - We do this because we can't use the `load` event or `onload` because neither fire.

Here's some example code to show that off:

```
var WindowObject = window.open();
WindowObject.document.write('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Jvh1OQm.jpg" />'); // This is your content to be printed
WindowObject.document.write('<script>(' + (function() {
    function checkReadyState() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            window.focus();
            window.print();
            window.close();
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkReadyState, 200); // May need to change interval
        }
    }

    checkReadyState();
}) + ')();</sc' + 'ript>');
```

Again, I'm going to stress this is a very bad way of doing what is wanted. I only provide this knowledge because I feel it could possibly be useful to someone.

Comment: Great write up and extremely useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `WindowObject.onload = function () { ... };` this way:

```
barcode.done(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    printText = jqXHR;
    var WindowObject = window.open();
    WindowObject.onload = function () {
        WindowObject.document.writeln(printText);
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
    };
});
```

Comment: It won't fire. For one, the new page is `about:blank` and won't ever actually load (`readyState` will always be "loading") unless a url is specified (though this can be worked around). Another issue is that onload (and the load event) won't fire if anything (e.g. loading an image) happens.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this out before I asked originally to no avail